# Nonlocal forcing of tiles in an aperiodic tiling with spectre tiles?

Tags: aperiodic-tiling

How much is known about the aperiodic tilings with spectre monotiles already?
Are the exciting existing theorems known from Penrose tilings with kites and darts also valid for spectre tilings?
Specifically, are there also infinite numbers of forced tiles caused by the possible vertices in Spectre tilings as in Penrose tilings of the plane?

Comment: I didn't want to change your meaning, so I didn't edit, but, just to make sure, did you really mean "the exciting theorems" instead of "the existing theorems"?

Comment: I really did mean exciting theorems because those really caught my interest when I first learned about Penrose tilings. But now I changed my wording to "exciting existing theorems".

Comment: What are "spectre tiles"?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson : "Spectre" is the name given to one of the aperiodic monotiles recently found. As the Pensose Kite and Dart, Spectres can tile the plane but do so only non-periodically.